# Not repeating line from text file

Tags: c#, string, random

The code read the text and returns a random string, but I want it not to show the same string again. Is there a way to do it?
I tried several ways but I am quite new so I could not find a way to do it with return.
Thank you
Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO; // For parsing text file, StringReader
using System.Collections.Generic; // For List
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
public class FileIO : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform contentWindow;
public GameObject recallTextObject;

public TextAsset wordfile; // Text file (assigned from Editor)
public List<string> lineList = new List<string>(); // List to hold all the lines read from the text 
file
public string abc { get; private set; }
void Start()
{
ReadWordList();
recallTextObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = GetRandomLine();
Instantiate(recallTextObject, contentWindow);
}
public void ReadWordList()
{
// Check if file exists before reading
if (wordfile)
{
string line;
StringReader textStream = new StringReader(wordfile.text);
while ((line = textStream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
// Read each line from text file and add into list
lineList.Add(line);
}
textStream.Close();
}
}
public string GetRandomLine()
{
// Returns random line from list

string abc = lineList[Random.Range(0, lineList.Count)];
return abc;

 }
```

Comment: shuffle `lineList` and always take next (`lineList[i++ % lineList.Count]`)

Comment: Are you allowed to _remove_ the elements that have been used from the list?

Comment: yes that is not a problem

Comment: There you go. You won't select a removed element even if the random happens to select the same index twice.

Comment: If you take Selvin's approach, remember to restrict `i` to `Count`, though. Otherwise Results will repeat after `i` "rolls over".

Answer (score 0):

Split the data into lineList and lineListUsed.

Every time you output a line move it from the lineList to lineListUsed.

And you can decide when and how you reuse the used lines.